# Is this stored procedure safe from SQL injection?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection

Stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Foo
    @bar varchar(100)
AS

SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE columnname LIKE '%' + @bar + '%'
```

I've tried passing various strings to this stored procedure, but to me it looks like this would be safe from a SQL injection since everything between and including the wildcards would result in a single string.

Comment: It's not the T-SQL that needs to be secured, but the code calling it. Can you show the code your calling it with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using C# and your code looks like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Foo", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bar", myTextBox.Text);
```

then yes!

If it looks like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("EXEC Foo '" + myTextBox.Text + "'", connection);
```

then no!

Comment: +1, spot on. Parameterized queries all the way (for those poor saps who still use classic ado.net. EF4 FTW)

Comment: I tried executing this within SQL Server Management Studio and the injection did not take place.  exec Foo ';drop table test;'.  Can you provide an example of how the second piece of code could be injected?

Comment: I think you are a bit confused about how SQL Injection works.  It's not something you would do from SQL Server management studio.  In my example putting `zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'; select 'i executed code here';` into myTextBox should cause unwanted code to be executed.

Comment: I misread the code example you had posted, you're correct that would result in unwanted code being executed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this would interpret all the data inside @bar as a single varchar(100) value.  You should still make sure something is passed in your app, since **LIKE '%%'** would default to returning everything in your DB.

Comment: I'll be enforcing a non-empty string value to be passed to the stored procedure.  Thanks.